# Current canceling circuit

Tags: oscillator, current-measurement

I have a question that I hope you can help me with. In the schematics below an oscillator is presented that is fed with both AC and DC voltages, to be polarized and to induce movement of it.

At the output I have a current that is equal to sum of the currents from the two branches and when I try to display them on a lock-in amplifier and oscilloscope it saturates and is not displaying anything.

Because of that I want to display just current. I'm without the Ic current, so I came up with the idea of a current canceling circuit. My mentor told me that I should use a variable capacitor plus some other components, but online I did not find helpful materials to help me resolve this issue.

What are your ideas for canceling these Ic currents so I can just have Im?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgGX4S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do you know the value of C0?

Comment: An oscilloscope takes a voltage input and not a current input.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen C0 is a known value.

Comment: @Andyaka I use sr830 dsp lock-in amplifier to record current.

Comment: What input are you using on the sr830 dsp lock-in amplifier? Why don't you just disconnect C0? Why not use a current probe on C1's pins/wires? Why not put an inductor across C0 to cancel its impedance to infinity?

Comment: The problem is that this is MEMS device and I just have one probe to give it an input and one probe to take the output. The schematics above is the representation of how it actually acts and the values of all components are calculated and are not directly measurable.

Comment: Because you have a capacitor in each path, the DC component is blocked, hence irrelevant

Comment: In theory, yes. But, in practice, if you tried that with the AC power, you'd be surprised to see nasty voltages coming through because the AC power is not a pure sine wave: distortion and spikes.

Answer (score 1):

This is one method: you can use a second capacitor, driven by the inverse of the source voltage. If your source is stiff enough (low internal resistance, or impedance), then you should be able to do a simple difference. Since you didn't give any values for the elements, I just used some random values:

[image: test]

`U1` delivers the same signal as the source, `V1`, but with a different polarity. Since `V1` has a 50 Ω output resistance, `R10` compensates. Or, simply use `I(C3)` with an inverted sign. Same thing. The plot shows the overlapping `I(L1)` and `I(R2)` -- meaning `I(C2)` is cancelled -- compared to `I(R6)` -- which is what the current looks like without compensation. Note that, depending on what frequencies you are working with, you'll need an opamp with a sufficient GBW.

Comment: Great answer, only it is not known what the output is connected to, but if you can manage to put the inverted-current circuit on an equivalent output impedance you're there.

Comment: @HarryH The circuits can be (fairly) easily added together. I've modified my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

You know C0, you know the operating frequency, so why not just tune out C0 with a parallel inductor?

Standard technique with ultrasonic transducers which your model closely resembles.

Alternatively, put the thing in a bridge circuit with a capacitor equal to C0 as the balancing impedance.